# Contacts suddenly changed colour

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, contacts

I'm using Android Lollipop 5.0.2 with the stock Contacts app on my Moto E. I can't remember what I was doing when this happened, but all of the contacts suddenly changed colour! And what's really annoying is that I liked the colours that had previously been chosen for them, but the new colours are really ugly.

What caused this, and is there any way to reverse it?

Comment: Please tell us which device and contacts app you are using.

Comment: Edited the question as appropriate.